# How to write rxjs catch and map functions using pipe after update

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

since rxjs got updated, my code is not working anymore. I realised that I need to use pipe and instead of catch catchError, but still something I'm missing. See code below. Thankful for help.

```
  public getAllTodos(): Observable<Todo[]> {
    return this.http.get(API_URL + '/todos')
    .pipe(
      map(response => {
       const todos = response.json();
       return todos.map((todo) => new Todo(todo));
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        this.handleError(err);
      })
   );
  }



    private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    console.error('ApiService::handleError', error);
    return Observable.throw(error);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

With the updated HttpClient module, we no longer need to use the .json syntax. Something like this:

```
  public getAllTodos(): Observable<Todo[]> {
    return this.http.get<Todo[]>(API_URL + '/todos')
    .pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        this.handleError(err);
      });
  }
```

Or if you still need to map to the actual objects:

```
  public getAllTodos(): Observable<Todo[]> {
    return this.http.get<Todo[]>(API_URL + '/todos')
    .pipe(
      map(todos => todos.map((todo) => new Todo(todo))),
      catchError(err => {
        this.handleError(err);
      })
   );
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. Unfortunately <Todo[]> throws the error "Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1."

Comment: Okay found error, needed to import Map this way: import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';